# How can I obtain King Attercop's spirit?

Tags: rift

I'm on the quest [To Catch a King](http://rift.magelo.com/en/quest/701662550/To-Catch-a-King) and I can't seem to obtain King Attercop's spirit.  If I kill him and then use the soul decanter item, nothing happens.  If I use it first, then he gets a debuff saying that his soul should be captured ... but it isn't, whether I wait or just kill him.  The only information I can find about this is someone having the same problem [on the Rift forums](http://forums.riftgame.com/general-discussions/general-discussion/148816-catch-king-quest-bugged.html) nearly 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is some sort of invisible timer or debuff in addition to the one that is actually shown.  You have to use the Decanter item on him right before you kill him — I did at about 10% and immediately killed him with 2 more hits, and was able to loot his bottled spirit.